# Android E/CAM_StateSaveOuc: exception whle saving result ro URI - no such directory

Tags: android, webview, android-camera

It can create a video's folder, but it doesn't work when creating Picture's folder. I got this error:

java.io.FileNotFoundException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or
directory)

The video works, but the picture...

```
        File imageStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MinhasImagens");

        if (!imageStorageDir.exists()) {
            imageStorageDir.mkdirs();
        }


        File file = new File(imageStorageDir + File.separator + "IMG_" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
        mCapturedImageURI = Uri.fromFile(file);

              final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        captureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCapturedImageURI);

        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        i.setType("image/*, video/*");

        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Parcelable[]{captureIntent, recordIntent});
```

Comment: Please read this article about **How to ask a good question** carefully and improve your answer accordingly: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: @RenéSpies Hey, thanks. What about now?

Comment: There is still room for improvement. Nobody wants to read your code for you. Briefly explain what you want to do, what is happening and what your expected result is. Use code snippets only if really necessary, e. g. where the error points you to, if you have any error. Think about your problem on your own before and determine where the problem occurs in your code before asking a question.

Comment: @RenéSpies and now?